# How to customize a "select" HTML form element with CSS 3?

Tags: html, forms, css

I cannot change the size of a select HTML form element without having ugly results, and totally different depending of the browser.

Do you know a method like the one 37 Signals did (unfortunately only for Webkit) : http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2609-customizing-web-forms-with-css3-and-webkit

Or any method / workaround which work on FF/safari/Chrome (and maybe IE ;-) ?

I create a form with huge elements : easy to have huge buttons or input[text], but so far impossible to do the same with select.

Thanks !

Comment: Well, like most other form elements, `<select>` can't be reliably styled since its default look is derived from a browser's GUI, or the OS GUI. That is, browser vendors choose how they want to render it.

Answer (score 8):

This is sadly still not possible reliably across browsers and operating systems. Way to go is actually a javascript-based solution that emulates a select field.

Answer (score 7):

You can style your select box with this jQuery:

http://www.adamcoulombe.info/lab/jquery/select-box/

It is easy to implement and degrades nicely (to default select) in browsers that do not support it (IE6).

**jQuery plugin** (included in download link):

```
customSelect.jquery.js
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').customStyle();
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.customStyleSelectBox {
/* Styles For Your Select Box */
}

.customStyleSelectBox.changed {
/* You can use this if you want a different style after user has made a selection */
}

/* on the next line we add a down arrow on the right to indicate that it is a select box */
.customStyleSelectBoxInner {
background:url(canvas-list-nav-item-arrow-.gif) no-repeat center right;
}
```

**Image preview:**

[image]

Comment: How did you go @Zouzouwizman? Did you find this jQuery plugin useful?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, CSS3 doesn't contain any extra features for styling `<select>` boxes. Furthermore, any attempt to style them using CSS will end up in a cross-browser chop suey mess.

The way to go would be Javascript/jQuery, [here's a jQuery one](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/selectBox/) that I've used in the past. If a user has Javascript turned off, it'll just default to a normal `<select>` element.

Feel free to browse around for a solution that meets your needs, you might need a vanilla Javascript one if you're not already using jQuery.

Answer (score -2):

To hide select arrow you can use that workaround

```
select {
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 120%;
}
```